# Function to control servos

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, variables, functions

I'm trying to control 6 servos while writing a lean code. I think the function call isn't correctly yet and I think that the variables (pos_n, open_n, servo_1) in the for loop do not get inserted, but instead the string just gets inserted.

I think I have come a long way to not make this a bulky code.

What changes makes this function working, so that the call openValve(1) and openValve(2); work for both servos?

```
#include <Servo.h>
const int buttonPin = 2;
int buttonState = 0;

Servo servo_1;
const int pos_1 = 0;
const int open_1 = 105;
const int clos_1 = 10;
//Servo servo_2;
//const int pos_2 = 0;
//const int open_2 = 104;
//const int clos_2 = 9;

String servo_n, pos, pos_n, servo, openServo, open_n;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  servo_1.attach(11);
}

void loop() {
  openValve(1); // call the function
  while (true);
}

void openValve(n) {
  int n = 3;
  pos = "pos_";
  pos_n = (pos + n);
  Serial.println(pos_n);

  servo = "servo_";
  servo_n = servo + n;
  Serial.println(servo_n);

  openServo = "open_";
  open_n = openServo + n;
  Serial.println(open_n);

  // DONT USE STRING BUT THE VARIABLE CONTENTS ??
  for (pos_n = pos_n; pos_n <= open_n; pos_n += 1) {
    servo_n.write(open_n);
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to write "lean" code, then using the `String` object is not going to make it "lean". The second thing I noticed, was that the code doesn't compile. The first error is "error: 'n' was not declared in this scope. I don't think this is the correct syntax: "void openValve(n) {". HINT: The "n" is an issue. Please fix the syntax errors then edit your question to show us some code that does compile.

Comment: variables in the loop do not get inserted into what?

Comment: @VE7JRO could you give me a hint what I then should use instead of the String object?

Comment: @Ludo: Plain C strings, i.e. arrays of `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are totally misunderstanding, about variables and types and how using multiple servos with 1 function can work, and that this is your real question and not the thing with inserting variables (whatever you mean by that).

You are trying to put together a string and use it as variable name. That does not work. A string is only a variable/instance of type/class `String`. It cannot have methods of the `Servo` class. Also function parameters each have their own type. You cannot provide a value of a different type to this parameter. `Servo.write()` takes an integer value. It cannot use a String value. Thus the code inside the for loop is nonsense and won't compile. I would suggest doing some C++ tutorials from the web, that explain, how variables work in C++.

Instead you have to use multiple variables of the type `Servo`, one for each servo motor, that you are using. These variables are instances of the `Servo` class, which implements all the servo related functions (like write) Each motor gets it's own pin on the Arduino. You can put these `Servo` objects into an array, so that they can be indexed by an integer number. For example you can define the following variable in the global scope:

```
#define N_SERVOS 6
Servo servos[N_SERVOS];
```

This creates an array of type `Servo` with 6 elements. Each element is one independent servo object. (Note, that I used a define to easily change the number of attached servos when changing the code). You can reach an individual servo object by indexing it:

```
servos[3].write(pos);
```

This would write a new position to servo 4 (4 because array indices are starting from 0). Now we need to attach each Servo object to one pin of the Arduino. I would create an extra array, which contains the corresponding pin numbers - also at global scope:

```
int servo_pin[N_SERVOS] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
```

Here I used pins 6 to 11, but you can change them, as you like. Then in the `setup()` function we loop over our servo elements and corresponding pin numbers and attach the servo objects to the pins:

```
for(int i=0;i<N_SERVOS;i++){
    servo[i].attach(servo_pin[i]);
}
```

And now you can rewrite your `openValve()` function corresponding to that. I don't understand, what you wanted the servo to do in the for loop, so I will leave this to you. First you need to correct the syntax at the function declaration. You didn't specify the type of the parameter `n`. It has to look like:

```
void openValve(int n){
```

And then you shouldn't declare a new variable with the same name, so delete the line `int n=3;`. Then you can delete all the weird string concatiation. Then you need to fix the for loop (as I wrote I will leave that to you, since you didn't explain, what the servo should actually do there). And finally you need to rewrite the servo write line like described above:

```
servo[n].write(new_pos);
```

Note, that `new_pos` is just a placeholder here, for whatever values you need to write to the servo (as already said, I don't understand, what exactly you want the servo to do).

---

> what I then should use instead of the String object?

The `String` class from the Arduino framework can get you into memory trouble (to be exactly memory fragmentation). You can read [Majenko's blog post about Arduino Strings](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/) for further explanations.

Instead you should use `char` arrays aka C-Strings. You create a buffer with a fixed length, that is big enough to hold the biggest chunk of data, that you need to process. Let's say you need at max 30 characters. Every C-String is terminated by a zero ('\0'). This zero also needs space in the buffer. So the actual buffer size is 31.

```
char string_buffer[31];
```

You can even directly initialize it with a string value:

```
char string_buffer[31]="Teststring";
```

You can use `sprintf()` to put a formatted string into the buffer. For example a string with a number:

```
sprintf(string_buffer, "Number: %d", 50);
```

will put the string "Number: 50" to the buffer and will terminate it with a zero.

Comment: I am a bit stuck in thinking like PHP code with inserting 'variables' :p Thanks for your elaborate answer!

Comment: @Ludo If you think, that my answer is correct, you can mark is as correct. Then others can see, that this actually solved your problem.